# Oracle Data Modeler - Conectar a Banco MySQL

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, oracle

Olá!

Estou tendo problemas a cerca de dois dias sobre como conectar o ODM ( Oracle Data Modeler) a uma base mysql.
O processo em todos os locais que eu encontrei consiste em:

-Iniciar o Oracle Data Modeler (ODM)
-No ODM, seguir Tools -> Preferences, Data Modeller -> Third Party JDBC Drivers
-adicionar o jconn.jar ou mysql-connector.jar  ou sajdbc4.jar (já tentei com todos)
-Reiniciar o ODM
-Seguir File -> Import -> Data Dictionary

Neste momento deveria existir uma aba para se conectar ao MYSQL ou JDBC, mas ainda assim só existe apenas a aba 'Oracle'. Alguém sabe o que está acontecendo? E como proceder?
 Grato desde já!

Comment: Resolvido, problema com a versão do ODM